# How to Recursively Create a Tree with Cypher (Neo4j)

Tags: recursion, graph, neo4j, tree, cypher

I'm trying to replicate an SGF game tree on Neo4j with Cypher. The tree is of this shape:

```js
type GameTree = {
  id: number;
  data: { [key: string]: string[] };
  parentId: number | null;
  children: GameTree[];
};
```

This is the creation query I'm trying to work out:

```
UNWIND $moves AS move

MATCH (parent)

WHERE ((parent:GameNode) OR (parent:MoveNode))
  AND parent.game_id = $gameId
  AND parent.id = move.parentId

CREATE   (parent)
        -[:NEXT_MOVE]
       ->(:MoveNode{
           game_id: $gameId,
           id:      move.id
         })
```

Initially, the root of the tree is a `GameNode`, which I create separately, because it holds interesting metadata. Anyways, this won't work like this because, at the time of the `UNWIND` and `MATCH` clauses, there exists only one parent, the rest of them will/should be created recursively.

Is there a way of doing this recursive creation in Cypher? Maybe there's some recursive keyword I can't seem to find (this seems like such a common kind of problem...)? Maybe there's a useful APOC procedure somewhere?

As a workaround, I'm thinking about creating all the `MoveNode`s first, and then using the query above to string them back together. It would look like this:

```
// 1. Create All The Move Nodes

UNWIND $moveNodes AS move

CREATE (:MoveNode{
         game_id: move.game_id,
         id:      move.id
       })

// 2. Tie them to their Parents

WITH move

MATCH (parent{
        game_id: move.game_id,
        id:      move.parentId
      }),
      (m:MoveNode{
        game_id: move.game_id,
        id:      move.id
      })

WHERE parent:GameNode
   OR parent:MoveNode
  
CREATE (parent)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->(m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each query execution is for a single chain of moves that are in order of play, and the parent `GameNode` already exists, then you can use the following:

```sql
UNWIND $moveNodes AS move
CALL {
    WITH move
    MATCH (parent:GameNode|MoveNode {game_id: $gameId, id: move.parentId})
    CREATE (parent)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->(m:MoveNode {game_id: $gameId, id: move.id})
}
```